# Find an optimal curve in order to minimalize the integral.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Let $F:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $T$ be a positive real number.

Functions $f_{1},f_{2}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable.

Let $S[f_{1},f_{2}]:=\int_{0}^{T}F(f_1(t)+if_2(t))dt$

Now, consider such functions $f_1, f_2$ so that expression $S[f_1,f_2]$ is as low as it is possible.

> Are there a system of differential equations, that is satisfied by $f_1,f_2$?

Is there an analogy to the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Regards

Comment: If the integral does not involve any derivatives of $f_1,\;f_2$, then you won't need any differential equations.

Comment: Then how can i find these functions $f_{1},f_{2}$ to get $S$ as low as possible?

Comment: Say you have $F(x)$; how to make _this_ expression as low as possible?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know it.

Comment: Imagine you haven't even started learning integrals yet, and you just want to find the minimum of $F(x)$ (without an integral around it). Can you do that?

Comment: Why are you assuming that i don't know the integrals?

Comment: I never said that. I said "_imagine_ that you don't know them".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109382/discussion-between-mkultra-and-ivan-neretin).